# How can I interpret a shannon entropy value less than $1$?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

Say we have a sequence of letters AAAB and throw them into an urn. The game now is to pick a letter out of the urn and then guess it by asking yes/no questions.

In my understanding, the entropy now gives me the average number of questions I need to ask to guess the letter I picked.

Calculating the entropy for the above example gives me

$$H = -\frac{3}{4}\log_2(\frac{3}{4})-\frac{1}{4}\log_2(\frac{1}{4})\approx 0.811$$

How can I interpret this in case my interpretation of the entropy is right? Is it not that I need at least 1 question to ask, e.g. "Is is A?" How can the average number

Comment: Related, almost dup https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768800/if-entropy-says-the-number-of-bits-an-information-needs-why-in-this-case-its-l

Answer (score 2):

You need fewer than one question, on average, to guess correctly.  After all, in the limiting case of $AAAA$ you need *zero* questions to guess correctly!

Nothing mysterious here!

In the stated problem, if you guess $A$ (without question), you'll be right most of the time.  All these entities are probabilistic, of course.

Comment: I understand it for the case AAAA, since there is no other letter to chose from. 

But in what case could 0 questions lead me to a guaranteed right answer given AAAB?

For me, it is mysterious.

Comment: Ah okay thanks for the edited version. I thought one has to raise a question until one reaches a guaranteed right answer, i.e. is not allowed to just throw a guess